# "Take our short survey" link not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

Today I got this banner at the top of the screen:

[image]
So I clicked the link to take the survey, but the page it opened up immediately redirected back to https://stackoverflow.com/, and the banner continues to pop up every time I open a new page. I assume that either I shouldn't be seeing the banner, or it should take me to a survey page.

Comment: Interesting. We had another similar report a couple weeks back, and I thought we fixed the issue there. Sorry about the inconvenience, we'll investigate further.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Chrome version 77.0.3865.90 64 bit on Linux if that helps.

Comment: Also not working on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more bug fixes later... I believe we've now resolved survey banner display issues. One thing remains - where Qualtrics may not let you actually fill out the survey if you've filled it out before on the same device. We're working on that issue separately.