# Survey banner is not working (again)

Tags: bug, survey, short-survey

I have the same question as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389789/take-our-short-survey-link-not-working). But since that bug was fixed I think creating a new post is adequate?

When loading SO I'm getting a blue banner with the text

> How are we doing? Please help us improve Stack Overflow. Take our short survey

[image: blue banner]

If I press on "Take our short survey" I get to page with the following text

> You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.

[image: survey error message]

The button redirects you from `https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect` to `https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/xxx?Code=LOG`.

It appears on every SO question page I open and disappears after clicking on the button. Is this a temporary issue?

I'm using Firefox 70.0.1 if this is relevant.

Comment: This year I'll not compile the developer survey because the last year, I've no got the badge after compile it.

Comment: Looks like this was never fixed. I get it it in 2020 and I'm sorry for the state of this site...: _How are we doing?_ Not so well.